# Write value of clicked data-table row into child component html with Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have created a data-table and i need the data in a child-component if i click on a row.

In Console log i get the row data but i can not read it in the child-compontent. 
I'm very new to Angular, i understand to write some easy strings to child, but not an Array or an Object.

I created a stackblitz for my problem, if you open the console and do a click on a row you get the object, how to write object data in the html of the child-component?!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vr9fqv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxedz5?embed=1&file=src/app/childComponent/child.component.ts)**

app.component.html

```
<app-child-component [rowData]="rowData"></app-child-component>
```

app.component.ts

```
rowData = {};


toggleDetails(row) {    
  this.rowData = row;
}
```

child.component.ts

```
@Input() rowData: any;
```

child.component.html

```
<p *ngFor="let item of rowData | keyvalue">{{item.key | titlecase }}: {{item.value}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass it as input to your child component :

ts

```
export class ChildComponent  {
  ...
  @Input() data : any ;
```

...
    }

html

```
<app-child-component [data]="dataRow"></app-child-component>
```

check the stackblitz demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4t5bmq